# Trouble embedding hrefs with mustache

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I am currently trying to generate a dynamic table of information for an html doc (keys and summaries) using mustache as the templating engine.

However my issue is embedding an href inside of the `<a>` tag for my key. The table generates dynamically, as the keys and summaries display correctly but the value of the href is the same for each of the keys and summaries(the first value). How do I make each key/summary have a different link/href? I have tried so many workarounds but cannot seem to find a solution when utilizing mustache. Is this possible when using mustache?

Any help is appreciated. My table code and JavaScript table are shown below.

```html
 {{#records}}
  {{#jKey}}

  <tr class="c29">
    <td class = c105 colspan="1" rowspan="1"><span class="c55 c71 c130"><a class="c49" href="{{#jLink}}{{jL}}{{/jLink}}">{{jK}}</a></span></td>
    <td class="c98"></td>
    <td class="c114" ></td>
    <td class="c12">{{jSprint}}</td>
    <td class="c126"></td>
    {{/jKey}}
    {{/records}}
  </tr>
```

```js
var Data = {
    "jKey": [
        {"jK": issues[0].key + ": " + issues[0].summary},
        {"jK": issues[1].key + ": " + issues[1].summary},
        {"jK": issues[2].key + ": " + issues[2].summary},
        {"jK": issues[3].key + ": " + issues[3].summary},
        {"jK": issues[4].key + ": " + issues[4].summary},
        {"jK": issues[5].key + ": " + issues[5].summary},
        {"jK": issues[6].key + ": " + issues[6].summary},
        {"jK": issues[7].key + ": " + issues[7].summary},
    ],
    "jLink": [
        {"jL": issues[0].link},
        {"jL": issues[1].link},
        {"jL": issues[2].link},
        {"jL": issues[3].link},
        {"jL": issues[4].link},
        {"jL": issues[5].link},
        {"jL": issues[6].link},
        {"jL": issues[7].link}
    ],
    "jSprint": versionName,
    "jTasks" : "array of info",
    "relDate": today,
    "cYear"  : yyyy
  };
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? What is the actual value of `Data`? (i.e. what you've shown includes variables for most values) Lastly, and this could be my misunderstanding of mustache, why are you beginning the `{{#records}}{{#jKey}}` loop before the initial `<tr>` but ending the loop before closing it?

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for the response, I placed the end tags there by accident but placing them after the <tr> has no bearing on the outcome of the table being rendered. As for the Data I'm using its just an array of issues from Jira which I've then gathered various info from such as the keys, links, and summaries. I've left a link to an image of my table below (as I cannot edit).     https://imgur.com/a/CxDNina

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get each href to be unique now, my `Data` structure was changed so that each `"jK": issues[0].key + ":  " + issues[0].summary` also has an accompanying link in that part of the `Data` like this:

```js
"jK": issues[0].key + ":  " + issues[0].summary, "jL":issues[0].link
```

So now when the table is generated each of the links embedded in the key and summary bring you to a different page.